# SELECT with 2 optgroups build with KnockOut resets the value to empty

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js

I have this HTML

```
<select data-bind="value: $data.id">
    <optgroup label="Regions" data-bind="foreach: countries.regions.names">
        <option data-bind="html: $data.name, value: $data.value"></option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Countries" data-bind="foreach: shipping.allCountries">
        <option data-bind="html: $data.name, value: $data.code"></option>
    </optgroup>

</select>
```

With this javascript which is being prefilled with an ID in either of the 2 `optgroups`. The ID is always present!

```
this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
```

But after the `select` is built by KnockOut, the value of `this.id()` is empty, and will return `undefined`. When I subscribe to the field, it gives me a notification it is being updated with nothing.

My current (dirty) fix:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    self.id(data.id);
}, 500);
```

This works, but of course is not recommended.

Also, after selecting another element in the `select` and returning to the original value, it is fine too.

How do I fix this problem?

*note: the correct element **is** selected.*

Comment: `$data` is implicit, you don't have to use it (i.e. `<select data-bind="value: id">` etc is fine).

Comment: unless of course there are globals with the same name. I like to keep it clean and prevent any issues with global variables. It's a big application

Comment: If you want to keep it clean, you should avoid globals. ;) Also, it's not an issue. Local variables shadow global ones, there is no way a scoping issue can bite you here. See http://jsfiddle.net/jcFA8/ (More than that, it even *fails with an error* if the thing you bind to is not a property of `$data`. Knockout will not silently use anything other than `$data`. http://jsfiddle.net/jcFA8/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this fails is because the `value` of the `<select>` element is bound before its contents are bound using `foreach` and that the `value` binding will reset the model value to whatever is currently selected in the element if the model value can't itself be selected.

Example of problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/8r6KY/

There are two solutions to this.

#### 1. Prevent model value from being reset

One solution is to prevent the `value` binding from resetting the model value using a new binding option available in Knockout 3.1 (currently in Beta), `valueAllowUnset`.

```
<select data-bind="value: $data.id, valueAllowUnset: true">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/D6dR2/

#### 2. Binding contents before value

The second solution is to get the `<option>` elements in place before the `value` is bound. This can be done with a custom binding on the element that binds the contents early.

```
<select data-bind="bindInner, value: $data.id">
```

Binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindInner = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/ETFsa/

#### Recommendation

The first option uses a built-in solution, but does have a downside that the UI selection happens using `setTimeout` (within the `value` binding). Thus you could have a visible change in the selection as the view is initialized. The second option is, I think, the better one, although you could, of course, use both of these together to doubly fix the problem.

Comment: The third solution would be to prevent hacking around the issue altogether: Using an autocomplete library and a plain old text field instead of a pre-populated `<select>`. Alternatively an `optgroups` custom binding on the select would do the trick, too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your countries.regions.names is actually pointing to the correct place. If those options don't exist then the values won't exist.

Comment: thanks, but that is fine. It all works, and all data is filled correctly. The observable is just resetted for some reason.